# C# 3DES encryption to C decryption

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, encryption

I have created a C# assembly that does 3DES encryption/encryption and tested it. I now need to decrypt the data on a remote machine for an install. .NET is not guaranteed to be present when my native process runs, so I need to decrypt it using Win32 C++ methods. This is for a commercial applicaiton, so third party libraries are going to need to flexible with their licensing. I would prefer a simple example to get me started. Most of the examples I have found so far require importing session keys. I'm not using those. I am encrypting on machineA with .NET 2.0, and passing over to machineB where I will retrive the key and decrypt with native Win32 API's. Can anyone point me in the right direction with some examples?

I know I need to start with `CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFY_CONTEXT)`. 
However, the next step appears to be import key and it looks like it requires (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/228786). Is this correct, or am I making this too difficult. I have a basic understanding of encryption. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "to MachineB where I will retrieve the key and decrypt..." do you already have the plaintext key and are looking to import it into a crypto context to perform your decryption? (I'm assuming you're already familiar with block cipher encryption modes (CBC, ECB, etc.).?

Comment: Why not simply find an LGPL C++ 3DES out there and wrap it for C#, use the raw C++ for remote machine?

Comment: @Martheen Because C# *has* a full [cryptographic security namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx). Why bring in a third-wheel when you don't have to? 3DES is 3DES, so long as you conform to the proper key setup, block mode, and padding mode. System.Security.Cryptography will do what the OP wants as will C++ via WinCrypt. He just needs to get his keys setup correctly (which is often the hardest part of dealing with Crypto on Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the following code:

```
#define TRIPLEDES_KEYSIZE 24
#define TRIPLEDES_BLOCKSIZE 8

...

BYTE key[TRIPLEDES_KEYSIZE] = { ... };

...

HCRYPTKEY hKey;

typedef struct
{
    BLOBHEADER hdr;
    DWORD cbKeySize;
    BYTE rgbKeyData [TRIPLEDES_KEYSIZE];
} KEYBLOB;

KEYBLOB keyBlob;
memset(&keyBlob, 0, sizeof(keyBlob));
keyBlob.cbKeySize = TRIPLEDES_KEYSIZE;
keyBlob.hdr.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
keyBlob.hdr.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
keyBlob.hdr.aiKeyAlg = CALG_3DES;
memcpy(keyBlob.rgbKeyData, key, TRIPLEDES_KEYSIZE);

BOOL res = CryptImportKey(hCryptProv, (const BYTE*)&keyBlob, sizeof(keyBlob), 0, 0, &hKey);
if (res)
{
    res = CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_MODE, CRYPT_MODE_ECB, 0);
```

Please note you can use `CRYPT_MODE_ECB` or `CRYPT_MODE_CBC` in the call to the function `CryptSetKeyParam` with `KP_MODE` option depending on what you want to do. You can set an IV by for example the following code

```
res = CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_IV, iv, 0);
```

which makes only sense in a `CRYPT_MODE_CBC` like mode.

Please note there is also a different 3DES mode (`CALG_3DES_112`) working with only 112 Bit key (i.e. with two normal DES keys). You have to modify the code if you want to use this mode.

Edit:

You should write some classes in C++ to manage all things of the CryptoApi. It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: If all he wants to do is decrypt some data with a naked 3DES key he should be able to do it without a yacppwc. (yet another C++ wrapper class). The API code here looks correct, and you took the time to mention he needs to know whether he's in CBC mode, etc, and potentially having to set the IV param. You even mentioned 2-key, which is more than most people think about, so +1.

Comment: Thank you Fermat2357, this is exactly what I was looking for to get me started! I'll run some tests and post if necessary. Thanks a bunch!